# PDFsharp: The name 'Process' does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I have been trying to install the PDFsharp library for the purpose of writing PDF records and came across a problem. It keeps saying that the Process does not exist in current context. I did a google and had no luck and a tinker to see if I can get it to work and no luck either. Below is the code I am using to test the library (pulled from the PDFsharp wiki)

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(); 
document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp"; 
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();  
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);     
XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic); 
gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height), XStringFormats.Center); 
string filename = "HelloWorld.pdf"; 
document.Save(filename);
process.Start(filename);
```

And these are the components I currently have in use.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using PdfSharp; 
using PdfSharp.Drawing; 
using PdfSharp.Pdf; 
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
```

I am probably being daft but can anyone see what I am doing wrong to throw this error?

Comment: C# is case-sensitive - and if you copy samples correctly you won't have problems like that. ;-)  If you download the PDFsharp source you will also find all samples with complete source code, projects, and solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
process.Start(filename);
```

and it has nothing to do with `PDFsharp`. You have to resolve that

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
Process.Start(filename);
```

Comment: Perfect! You are a star! So I can understand. What is the relation between the Process and the System.Diagnostics?

Comment: You are calling static [`Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) method of `Process` class, which is located in `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process is not working... I get a compilation error saying that process does not exist in the namespace system.diagnostics.. could you please help me

Comment: @kirushan, search for exact error message. If that doesn't work then simply ask a new question. Please make sure to include as much info as you can: error itself, the code you are using, etc. I suspect you aren't creating *standard* .net application, but a more *specialized*, e.g. uwp or xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add the "using" Directive:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
```