# The name 'process' does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm going through the iText7 jump start example as shown [here](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-1). in the "Publishing a database" section. I created a basic .Net Console application and copy-and-pasted teh code. I keep getting "The namespace 'process' does not exist in the current context" error on lines `process(table, line, bold, true);` and `process(table, line, font, false);`

I see a similar question in reference to PDFsharp [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605767/pdfsharp-the-name-process-does-not-exist-in-current-context) It says to use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`, but that does not seem to solve my problem.

```
var writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
var document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4.Rotate());
document.SetMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
var font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA);
var bold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA_BOLD);
var table = new Table(new float[] { 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1 });
table.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));
StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(DATA);
var line = sr.ReadLine();
process(table, line, bold, true);
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  process(table, line, font, false);
}
sr.Close();
document.Add(table);
document.Close();
```

What's the proper way to remove the "The namespace 'process' does not exist in the current context" error?

Comment: Just below the code you copy pasted, they have another code for the `process(...)` function

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because scrolling down the page you took this code from reveals the implementation of the process method.

Comment: Note that tutorials like these may sometimes display one block of code before displaying a related block of code. Note that because it doesn't reference a static class (e.g. `Process.DoSomething(...)`), or a defined variable (e.g. `myProcessInstance.DoSomething(...)`), it's evident that the method is defined within the same class as the method you have displayed. Therefore it's a method that you have to implement - and the article goes on to do so.

Comment: You should add 'static' to your process implementation and follow the naming convention, which threw me off. But yes, this question should be closed

Comment: Given the code presented, the only reason you might need to add `static` is if the calling method is also `static`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read the rest of the article. The implementation is lower down.

[image]